# org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsException: You are using a no-op implementation of the CDP

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome-devtools-protocol, selenium4

Please be sure to include an implementation on the classpath, possibly by adding a new (maven) dependency of `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-vNN:4.1.3` where `NN` matches the major version of the browser you're using.
selenium-devtools-vNN:4.1.3
I am getting the maximum version for chrome is 99 in enable Network methods. but I am running chrome version 106 currently. How to achieve the compatibility issue resolution.

//import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v99.network.model.Response;
//import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v99.network.model.Request;
above are the maximum Versions I am getting for Devtools upon suggestions provide by Eclipse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

no proposal has been made to import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v107.log.Log;  can't able to import any perticular version instead its downloading org.openqa.selenium.devtools.idealized   so Log.enable not working